# ABAQUS - create Contact Damping Object in Python Script

Tags: python, abaqus

So i was trying to creat a damping object under interaction property.
Below is the damping object arguments and such.

```
**definition**
A SymbolicConstant specifying the method used to define the damping. Possible values are DAMPING_COEFFICIENT and CRITICAL_DAMPING_FRACTION. The default value is DAMPING_COEFFICIENT.

**tangentFraction**
The SymbolicConstant DEFAULT or a Float specifying the tangential damping coefficient divided by the normal damping coefficient. The default value is DEFAULT.

**clearanceDependence**
A SymbolicConstant specifying the variation of the damping coefficient or fraction with respect to clearance. Possible values are STEP, LINEAR, and BILINEAR. The default value is STEP.

If definition=CRITICAL_DAMPING_FRACTION, the only possible value is STEP.

**table**
A sequence of pairs of Floats specifying the damping properties. The items in the table data are
described below.

**Table data**
If definition=DAMPING_COEFFICIENT and clearanceDependence=STEP, the table data specify the following:
• Damping coefficient.
If definition=DAMPING_COEFFICIENT and clearanceDependence=LINEAR or BILINEAR, the table
data specify the following: 
• Damping coefficient. 
• Clearance.
    Two pairs must be given for clearanceDependence=LINEAR and three pairs for clearanceDependence=BILINEAR. The first pair must have clearance=0.0, and the last pair must have coefficient=0.0.
 If definition=CRITICAL_DAMPING_FRACTION, the table data specify the following: 
        • Critical damping fraction.
```

So the definition i'm using is the CRITICAL_DAMPING_FRACTION. The only difficulty i run into is how to write for the "table" part. Below is my code:

```
myModel.interactionProperties['Prop-1'].Damping(definition = CRITICAL_DAMPING_FRACTION, table = ((6,),))
```

so from the manual, it says the table should be a sequence of pairs of floats, and expecting a tuple.Since for critical damping fraction, there is only one number needed. The error message I got is the " invalid damping table".

I really couldn't find out what I did wrong for the table part. Hope someone here can know where I'm wrong! THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition is correct, but you're missing definition for `clearanceDependence`. To make your command work, write the following:

```
myModel.interactionProperties['Prop-1'].Damping(definition = CRITICAL_DAMPING_FRACTION, table = ((6,),), clearanceDependence=STEP)
```

There is only one possible value for `clearanceDependence` property, which is STEP, but you need to define it anyway. Unfortunately, documentation is not that clear about that.

In the future, you can modify the interaction property manually in Abaqus and just read the value using Python. That way you'll see what it should look like. Plus, the abaqus.rpy file would contain the correct command.